# r ggplot2 facet_grid how to add space between the top of the chart and the border

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

Is there a way to add space between the labels on the top of the chart and the margin of a plot using ggplot's facet_grid.  Below is a reproducible example.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
Titanic %>% as.data.frame() %>%
filter(Survived == "Yes") %>% 
mutate(FreqSurvived = ifelse(Freq > 100, Freq*1e+04,Freq)) %>%
ggplot( aes(x = Age, y = FreqSurvived, fill = Sex)) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
facet_grid(Class ~ ., scales = "free") +
theme_bw() +
geom_text(aes(label = prettyNum(FreqSurvived,big.mark = ",")), vjust = 0, position = position_dodge(0.9), size = 2)
```

The resulting chart has the label of numbers right next to the border of the plot.

[image: picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way is to use the `expand` argument of scale_y_continuous:

```
dt = Titanic %>% as.data.frame() %>%
  filter(Survived == "Yes") %>% 
  mutate(FreqSurvived = ifelse(Freq > 100, Freq*1e+04,Freq))

ggplot(dt, aes(x = Age, y = FreqSurvived, fill = Sex)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  facet_grid(Class ~ ., scales = "free") +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_text(aes(label = prettyNum(FreqSurvived,big.mark = ",")), 
            vjust = 0, position = position_dodge(0.9), size = 2) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.1,0))
```

[image]

The downside of using `expand` is that it will add space both above and below the bars.  An alternative is to plot some invisible data on the graph at a height above the bars, which will force ggplt to expand the axis ranges to accomodate this dummy data.  Here I add some invisible bars whose height is 1.2* the actual bars:

```
Titanic %>% as.data.frame() %>%
  filter(Survived == "Yes") %>% 
  mutate(FreqSurvived = ifelse(Freq > 100, Freq*1e+04,Freq)) %>%
  ggplot( aes(x = Age, y = FreqSurvived, fill = Sex)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = FreqSurvived*1.2), stat = "identity", 
           position = "dodge", fill=NA) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  facet_grid(Class ~ ., scales = "free") +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_text(aes(label = prettyNum(FreqSurvived,big.mark = ",")), 
            vjust = 0, 
            position = position_dodge(0.9), size = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: To elaborate a bit: `expand` add in this case `0.1 * y_range + 0` to each y axis (default is c(0.05, 0)),

Answer (score 10):

I wanted to add to @dww 's answer, but don't have enough reputation.

The `expand` option actually will allow you to add space only to the top of your graph. From the `?expand_scale` help file:

```
# No space below the bars but 10% above them
ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = factor(cyl))) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expand_scale(mult = c(0, .1)))
```

Comment: `expand_scale` is now deprecated; use `expansion` instead.  Same functionality and arguments.   This answer is a perfect solution.